# How do I uninstall ruby from my cygwin installation

Tags: ruby, cygwin

My cygwin installation contains the following ruby binaries, how can I uninstall these binaries since I would like to use ruby 192 on my windows vista machine

```
ruby.exe
rubyw.exe
```

Comment: `rm`? Or use the Cygwin package installer, uncheck the 'ruby' programs and libraries.

Comment: Sometimes you wouldn't know what to remove and hence will prefer an uninstaller.

Comment: Which is why the suggestion to use the cygwin installer :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To uninstall any package on Cygwin, run `setup-x86.exe` or `setup-x86_64.exe` (which you should already have, or you can get them [here](https://cygwin.com/install.html)), select "ruby" under "interpreters", click the round arrow icon until it says "Uninstall", then continue.  This will remove the executables and libraries and take care of any dependencies.  You *could* remove the files directly, but that might leave the system in an inconsistent state, and you might miss something.

Cygwin doesn't seem to have Ruby 1.9.2 yet, unfortunately (*NOTE: I wrote this several years ago and I'm not currently able to check*).  How do you intend to install it?  If you're going to install a pure Windows (non-Cygwin) version of ruby, you may not need to uninstall the Cygwin version.  For example, I have both Cygwin Perl and ActiveState Perl on my Windows 7 system; I use one from the Cygwin environment, the other from the Windows environment.

Or I suppose you could build ruby 1.9.2 from source under Cygwin; in that case, yes, you would want to uninstall the Cygwin ruby installation first.

(As I write this update, the latest version of Ruby is 2.3.2.)

http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/ has more information about ways to install ruby (but nothing specific about Cygwin).

Comment: I tried it like you said. Ruby -v still shows me the same old ruby. I have ruby 2.x in cygwin.

Comment: What does `type -a ruby` (at a Cygwin bash shell prompt) tell you?

Comment: Actually, I deleted cywin install and data folders. Reinstalled it. Your command shows the windows ruby I had.

Comment: Cygwin's `setup.exe` (I think the name has since been changed; there's one for 32 bits and one for 64 bits) isn't going to remove a Windows Ruby installation. If you want to do that, you'll have to use some Windows-specific installation method, probably something like "Add/Remove Programs" (or whatever it's called in more recent versions of Windows).

Comment: [https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-packages](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-packages) did not work for me with ruby. `ruby -v` keeps prompting my ruby version.

Comment: @gugol: Perhaps you have a `ruby` executable other than the one installed by Cygwin. What does `type -a ruby` print?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried what says in Cygwin [docs](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.uninstall-packages):

> 2.18.
>
> How do I uninstall individual packages?
>
> Run Cygwin Setup as you would to install packages. In the list of
>   packages to install, browse the relevant category or click on the
>   `View'' button to get a full listing. Click on the cycle glyph until
>   the action reads`Uninstall''. Proceed by clicking ``Next''.

But it did not work, I did it for "All Users" and for "My User" when running Setup.

So I finally repeated the process but without checking "Select required packages(RECOMMENDED)" and that time it worked. Now:

```
$ ruby -v
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

As last step I deleted the `.gem` file in my home Cygwin folder.

Comment: Actually the only way I was able to remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io/) to install Ruby 1.9.2 while keeping your current version available. You'll need to have curl, git, automake and mingw to install and compile Ruby.